# Fetch server side data using typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, asp.net-mvc-4, typescript2.0

I am new in typescript and i am wondering how do we write the below code in typescript. My project is in asp.net MVC.
**Here is my code** :

```
    $("#EmployeeCode").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
           $("#EmployeeCode").val('');
           $.ajax({
           url: '/Admin/Search/Country/' + request.term,
           dataType: "json",
           type: "GET",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item,
                    val: item.split('-')[1],
                }
            }))
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            console.log(response.responseText);
        }
    });
},
select: function (e, i) {
    // $(this).val(i.item.val);
    $("#EmployeeCode").val(i.item.val);
},
minLength: 3
```

});

Comment: Well, depending upon the typescript rules you have set up, that *is* valid TypeScript.  If you have rules requiring types in place you need to add the type definition files.

If you don't have the type definition files you can either create them or cheat and just toss `:any` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is just a superset of javascript so javascript is valid. You can if you want just use it as it is.